# Flutter Web: Adding an HTML script on a specific page

Tags: html, flutter, linkedin-api, flutter-web

I would like to add a  to install the Linkedin Insights Tag on a specific page in my flutter web project. This would happen after navigating to a named route, and the script should be in that route specifically, so adding it to web/index.html does not work.

I haven't been able to find posts in SO nor dependencies that can help me with this. Would anyone have an idea on how to achieve this?